# The Three Retiree's Cipher

Tags: riddle, cipher, cryptic-clues

Three high school friends who took different paths after high school are now all enjoying retirement. Each one settled for a different job but all enjoyed cryptography throughout their lives.
Now having reunited they send each other encrypted messages to keep their minds sharp and prevent their knowledge from dwindling.

- One spent his life in the military.
- Another in the police force.
- The last a telecommunications company.

Currently they communicate using a homemade cipher they can all relate to.

```
!3B7BA2B3C 1CF 7A9A3B2ABD1F A7A1B 7A9A3B2ABD1F 7A2B7C2BD B7A1B.
!C4A 1C2E E1A2CB1F 3B7BA2B3C 2E7B 2AB 6A1AEE3C,
C7B9A2D 1F2B1A2D3A6A 4A7B2D 6A1AEEC7A2B1FF 0A1CDD 7A2B7C2BD B7A1B.
```

Can you crack their latest message???

To complete the problem you must:

```
 - Decrypt the message and find the author.
 - Explain clearly how the cipher works.
 - Explain what the cipher is based on.
```

**Hints**
After a few days I will post some more hints if this remains unanswered.

> They all share practical knowledge, they have been known to mumble.
>  The last thing they want to do is meet up, they are in their element.
>  They also like to abbreviate, time is of the essence.
>  Read between the lines systematically, these hints are not what they seem.
>  What is the solution to verbal communication errors? 
>  Shall I spell it out for you? Perhaps. 
>  Nate! Oh My Gosh, Get It Over With!

**PLEASE NOTE:** I have updated the cipher text due to minor errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message says:

> Money is numbers and numbers never end.
>  If it takes money to be happy,
>  your search for happiness will never end.

<sub>(which is a quote from Bob Marley)</sub>

---

The encryption process works as follows.

First, produce an alphabet based on the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), but by

> grouping the alphabet by the last letter of the corresponding radio code (alpha, delta, india, ... bravo, echo, ...). Assign each group a number and each word a letter based on the order they appear (credit to [Zandar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25608/the-three-retirees-cipher/#comment81664_27591) for working out this step).
>  So **A** = *alpha* = `1A` (first group, first word), **B** = *beta* = `2A` (second group, first word), etc.
>  Resulting in the following dictionary (code determined by column, then row):
>  `-  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`
>  `A: A B C F G H N Q U W`
>  `B: D E M J     O     X`
>  `C: I K Y       V`
>  `D: L R`
>  `E: P T`
>  `F: S`
>  <sub>(not sure what they'd do if they needed a **Z**, since that would require an 11th group...)</sub>

From here, you can encrypt your message easily, however:

> Once you have converted each letter into it's corresponding number/letter pair, if consecutive pairs use the same leading number, you drop the number in subsequent pairs (so `2A2B` becomes `2AB`).

Comment: OK, I followed this up until the last spoilerblock - how did you arrive at that?

Comment: I used the same strategy, but didn't think of repeating the previous number; I assumed that each letter had a 'default' number.  Regardless of the justification behind that particular mapping, you broke the cipher, and IMHO that's what matters.  Nice work!

Comment: @question_asker - see my [comment(s)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25608/the-three-retirees-cipher/27591#comment81646_25608) on the question itself... I still don't know how it actually works, I just reverse engineered it.

Comment: @Alconja aha! Gotcha. Still no clue on the why, though.

Comment: It looks like the letters are grouped by the last letter of their radio alphabet word, although I don't know whether there's a reason why they're assigned to specific numbers.

Comment: @Zandar - well done, I think that's all there is to it. The numbers are just the order they come in (per letter).

Comment: Maybe, since a lot of words and letters can sound similar when spoken over a phone, and they have a tendency to mumble, the last phonetic noise is the one most clearly heard, so that's how they order it? (not an expert on any account, just offering my 3 uncommon cents.)

Comment: well, actually, mumble makes me think of white noise, so that could be another reason, somehow?

Comment: Well done, that is correct, perfectly explained. By the way I personally just put "Z" as 9b.

Comment: @Daedric - btw, I'm not sure that anyone would've been able to make the leap from phonetic alphabet to that sorting method to get the cipher number/letters if they were solving it "forwards" (I.e. without knowing the solution). You gotta leave more breadcrumbs for people to solve encryption method blind.

Comment: @Alconja I did, just go and read the entire thing. There is plenty of hints. But how much should one spell the puzzle out for you? My other cipher was harder and no one complained.

Comment: @Daedric - Maybe I'm still not getting the hints then, because the phonetic alphabet step is definitely hinted at (and I think your original clues were fine), but I still can't see how you'd then make the leap to "take the last letter of each code word, group them, and relabel them based on order" to get the alphabet without having to first do the frequency analysis work to basically solve it anyway... (as for your question on how much one should spell things out, [this post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) has some good discussion).

Comment: @Daedric - oh, and finally, don't take any of this as criticism (well, beyond the constructive sense anyway). It was still a good puzzle, and I enjoyed working on it, just very hard. :)

Comment: @Alconja The first line and third line of the main text and the second line of hints are all metaphors on the subject. Once you realize the cipher uses the NATO phonetic alphabet you scan the post for hints as to how. Anyway ciphers are not meant to be easy (and this in my opinion was quite easy, on a complexity level), that is why frequency analysis, and other methods exist, they are meant to be used as a tool, and working backwards is fine. You should check my last one out: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13174/can-you-crack-the-magic-diarys-encrypted-message

Comment: @Daedric - fair enough, you've convinced me (frequency analysis, etc are most definitely valid techniques). And at the end of the day, the most difficult thing is getting the difficulty right. :)